# Ruby: how to ouput PDF object element?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, tags, embed, actionview

I am embedding a pdf file in rails view using embed tag, i have write it in simple html and its working fine but i need to write this tag in rails conventions.
The code is like:-

```
<object data="file1.pdf#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="720">
  <embed src="file2.pdf#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="720" />
</object>
```

Comment: sorry thats not file2.pdf in embed tag, its file1.pdf only

Answer (score 0):

It seems Ruby uses print to output to a client...

```
print 'Hello World!'
```

There is no "embed tag", that is an "object element"; using the correct terminology not only makes you look more professional to others though also greatly improves your ability to communicate in fewer steps. 99.9% of the time people are referring to an element, it is the whole element. A very rare correct reference to a tag would be something like, "In XHTML does the meta element self close or does it have an end tag?" (e.g. < meta / > or < meta >< / meta >).

Internet Explorer (as usual) has a bug that is unable to display flash objects correctly in certain situations such as with your code, I'm not sure if this applies to a PDF but they're both Adobe products so best to try this in IE7 to be sure. You need to have a movie parameter element.

Here is everything put together along with Ruby...

```
<object class="pdf" data="something.pdf" type="application/pdf">
 <param name="movie" value="something.pdf" />
 <p>This is alternative content that displays if the plugin is not suppoted.</p>
</object>
```

Another very important clarification: you need to have a height/width set or at least a minimum height and width set otherwise certain browsers (e.g. Firefox) will not load the resource. In fact when I change themes on my site if the dimensions change in the middle of the music playing the whole Flash object resets. Not such a big issue for a PDF though if it forces the browser to reload the PDF it may annoy your visitor and it's ALL about making sure your visitors aren't annoyed by doing things right the first time.

Lastly alternative content is any (X)HTML that appears inside the object element. You can add a link to download a PDF plugin if the client's browser doesn't already support one.

Hope this helps, feel free to ask for clarifications if need be.